# How to append some data in the data field in skb?

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, netfilter

In netfilter hook.

I tried the `skb_realloc_headroom` but this function will generate a new skb.

I want to append some data in skb->data, using the original skb , is it possible?

like [Extending packet header from within a Netfilter hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662749/extending-packet-header-from-within-a-netfilter-hook)

but I want to add some data in skb->data.

Comment: Sorry, [skb](https://www.google.com/search?q=skb) what?

Comment: @Evert Linux kernel socket buffer, he kinda should've said `sk_buff` instead